# Displaying HTML within a PHP variable

Tags: php

how would I echo out the `$dateSpan1` and `$dataSpan2` variable for HTML?

php code:

```
$dateSpan1 = '<span class=bydatepad>';
$dateSpan2 = '</span>';
$variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', ($dateSpan1 . 'F j, Y' . $dateSpan2 . $dateSpan1 . 'g:i a' . $dateSpan2));
$variables['submitted'] = t('By: ' . ' !username ' . ' !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
```

current results:

```
<00pam6 2015-06-15T10:05:00-04:00Mondayam0000=b1515am30America/New_Yorkpam15>June 15, 2015 <00pam6>
<00pam6 2015-06-15T10:05:00-04:00Mondayam0000=b1515am30America/New_Yorkpam15> 10:05 am<00pam6>
```

results I want:

```
Display: June 15, 2015 10:05 am 
HTML: <span class=bydatepad>June 15, 2015</span><span class=bydatepad>10:05 am</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should format your date without any html markup, and then add your markup.
And by the way add double quotes to html attribs.

```
$variables['date'] = '<span class="bydatepad">'.format_date(...).'</span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with fixed escape chars

```
$dateSpan1 = '\<span class=bydatepad\>';
$dateSpan2 = '\<\/span\>';
```

or you can make a function that does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($dateSpan1);
```

That should do it, just change the variable inside the function depending on what you want to display at that time